# Issue with implementing a Navigation Drawer in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation, drawer

I've been trying to implement a Navigation Drawer using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGcMLu1GJEc) tutorial series.
It is quite an old tutorial and it uses the android.support library instead of androidx so I tried to adjust it to use androidx instead but there a few bugs in the UI and functionality of the drawer.

When I launch the application on my emulator or on a physical device, the drawer looks like this (takes up the entire screen) and it does slide in and out from the left.

It would be really helpful if someone could point me to what I'm doing wrong or suggest a guide as to how to implement the Navigation drawer another way.

[This is how the UI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BCcC.png)

Here is my code:

[All code](https://github.com/michal2003pluk/Navigation_Drawer)

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mdnavigationdrawer">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I added this style in my themes.xml file:

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

activity_main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/NameHere"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/EmailHere" />

</LinearLayout>
```

drawer_menu.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_message"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"
            android:title="@string/Message" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_chat"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat"
            android:title="@string/Chat" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="@string/Profile" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:title="@string/Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
                android:title="@string/Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check the width of the `Linear Layout`, make it `wrap_content`.

Kotlin:

Here's a guide in 2020 to show you how: [Medium Article](https://proandroiddev.com/easy-approach-to-navigation-drawer-7fe87d8fd7e7?gi=ab86f781cacc)
A Video Guide: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do4vb0MdLFY)

Java:

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USenYOBJw9Y)

[Article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/navigation-drawer-in-android/)

Comment: Both the guides you mentioned are written in Kotlin. Will I be able to implement this using java.

Comment: I edited the answer with Java References :)

Comment: And yes you can, you will get the hang of it quickly